# How effective is topical fluorouracil to treat facial superficial basal cell carcinoma (BCC) after Imiquimod 5% cream failed to treat it?

Tags: dermatology, cancer, basal-cell-carcinoma

Both Imiquimod 5% cream and topical 5-Fluorouracil (5-FU) have been used to treat basal cell carcinoma (BCC) with a fair amount of success (~60 to 90% success rate at 5-year follow-up) {1}.

Imiquimod and 5-Fluorouracil work differently, e.g. from {1}:

> - Imiquimod is a toll-like
>   receptor that modifies the immune response via the up-regulation of cytokines and has the capacity to improve a person’s
>   immune response.
> - 5-Fluorouracil attacks cancer cells by inhibiting thymidylate
>   synthetase.

This makes me wonder: does it make sense to try 5-Fluorouracil in case Imiquimod 5% cream failed to treat a BCC. In other words, how effective is topical fluorouracil to treat facial superficial basal cell carcinoma (BCC) *after* Imiquimod 5% cream failed to treat it?

---

References:

- {1} Love WE, Bernhard JD, Bordeaux JS. Topical imiquimod or
  fluorouracil therapy for basal and squamous cell carcinoma: a
  systematic review. Arch Dermatol. 2009;145(12):1431–8. https://doi.org/10.1001/archdermatol.2009.291

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because needs more than community knowledge to be answered reliably.

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean by "needs more than community knowledge to be answered reliably."?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that a variety of your BCC related posts seem to ask things that despite your best efforts in researching primary literature and research papers did not yield satisfactory results. From that I concluded that what you are asking might need either studies or similar work and thought this SE was, from rather little response to previous similar inquiries on BCC, not having any specialist on this subject. Just my opinion, of course, and only a one vote.

Comment: @Thomas Closing expert questions will not help attract specialists.